# Android - Listening for incoming TCP/Socket messages in background

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask

I am trying to write a little application which sends TCP messages (with a PrintWriter) to a JAVA Server running on PC. Now the Client should listen in background for incoming messages from the Server. How can I listen for incoming messages an update the GUI with the message from background-task?

Comment: what have you tried? Please post your code and any error messages so we can help you

Comment: @Philip I don't have the code for the background service yet because I am searching for a good way to run it in background that also allows me to interact with the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to spin up a background thread for this.  Probably the easiest way to go is to use an AsyncTask and then use onPostExecute, or publishProgress, to safely display your message in the UI.

Check out the [Android docs on threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I searched for!